# Exchange Powershell attempting to gather all mailboxes that have send as permissions granted

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2013

I am working on a migration from on premise Exchange 2010/2013 to Office 365 Exchange online.  I am trying to collect a report of all mailboxes of user type and shared type that has send as permissions granted;  as well as the names of the mail users that have been granted the permission.  The code I am using is as follows.

`#Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox,usermailbox -resultsize unlimited | Get-ADPermission | where {($_.ExtendedRights -like "*Send-As*") -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not (($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -or ($_.User -like "S-1-5-*") -or ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM") -or ($_.User -like "BUILTIN\Administrators"))} | select User,identity  | Export-Csv $outfile`

The code seems to work but after a few minutes I get the following:

[image]

I have tried running the code from 3 different exchange servers and keep getting a variation of the same error and am at a loss.  I have even tried limiting it to just users and just shared mailboxes to no avail.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: please add error details as text - not as image.

Comment: Any perticular reason why you are trying to put this all in a oneliner ? For scripts like these (espacially in migration scenarios) I first tend to get a full list of all mailboxes and all permissions on them (and I save it for future reference) and THEN I process this list locally with Powershell by filtering the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular error is pretty specific. Size quotas are preventing success.

You can change the size to see if that resolves your issue.

```
winrm get winrm/config 

Default configuration

Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
...


winrm get winrm/config @{MaxEnvelopeSizekb="5000"}
```

Update, the above should have been set not get, a bad transpose.

```
winrm set winrm/config @{MaxEnvelopeSizekb="5000"}
```

Or the cmd that the OP (CBeale) noted.

```
Set-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config -ValueSet @{MaxEnvelopeSizekb = "5000"}
```

Comment: This was not quite right, but gave me the clue needed to resolve the issue.  the command I used looked like this  `Set-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config -ValueSet @{MaxEnvelopeSizekb = "5000"}`